# Is it secure to sell your old router?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, security

If you already removed your sim card is it secure to sell your old router? Is it possible to recover any personal information from the old router your going to sell, for eg. browsing data?

Comment: Just reset the router.

Answer (score 1):

The only potential security issue is with any configuration settings you have configured in the router, which may identify domains and IP addresses associated with you or your organization, and may contain user credentials including passwords.

However, as long as you perform a factory reset on your router, you will clear all such settings, so there should be no security issue.